# mysql - How can I correct an auto-increment field that has deleted rows (1,2,3,4,5 - is now 1,3,5) but I want it to be 1,2,3

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a database that I made using an "auto-increment" primary key.  Only now I went back and deleted some of the rows.

The problem is, that I would like the table to be 1->X without any holes in the numbered column (in other words it should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 - but now it's more like 1,2,3,7,8,10.

Is there a way I can re-set the values of this column to be incremented correctly via mysql???

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you have any foreign keys pointing to these IDs, they'll become invalidated.

Comment: Yes, the question is [why], auto-increment is for avoid duplication key.

Comment: What benefit do you gain from having no 'holes' in the numbering? An autoincrementing field is specifically intended NOT to refill these values, so that any deleted or modified records do not have their IDs changed. Once an ID is allocated it is not supposed to change.

Comment: I have no yet created the foreign table, having this table be a standard order is ideal for the project that I am working on

Comment: It is a very bad practice.

Comment: Define 'ideal'. If you rely on an autoincrement field having no gaps in the numbering, then the error is in your design, not the autoincrement behaviour.

Comment: its a mad scientist project, I need the ids to be ordered with no holes to run a side application with minimal upkeep.

Comment: It's almost effortless to retrieve the dataset, iterate through the rows and add the list of IDs to an array as you go. After that, your side application will not need to assume tight ordering and can use the array you populated to work with the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a user defined variable, which is incremented during every row, and an `order by` to prevent duplicate id's *during the update process:

```
SET @x := 0;
UPDATE mytable SET
id = (@x := @x + 1)
ORDER BY id;
```

See an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2217/2)

Comment: Thank you for the wildly more efficient solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE yourtable t
JOIN (SELECT id oldid, @id := @id + 1 newid
      FROM yourtable
      JOIN (SELECT @id := 0) var
      ORDER BY oldid) newid
ON t.id = oldid
SET t.id = newid
```

The `ORDER BY` and `ON` conditions are needed to prevent it from temporarily creating duplicate keys, which causes an error.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/099d8/1)

Comment: Confirmed, demo works.  Now trying out on my huge dataset!  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in select process:

```
SELECT @s:=@s+1 AS fake_id, tbl.*
FROM tbl, (SELECT @s:= 0) AS tmp_tbl
```

Comment: He wants to change the IDs permanently, not do this on every select.